Ruby on Rails: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer in stylesheet_link_tag
There is a Type Error raised on the layout file application.html.erb:
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer):
    35:   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    36:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    37:
    38:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    39:
    40:   <%= favicon_link_tag('favicon.ico') %>

Web page in development shows that it is raised on:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
It also does happen with javascript_include_tag. This happens in my windows PC
This project runs fine on Linux and on Docker, however running it directly on windows would help me to try to fix some issues that are occuring only on the production environment.
Here is the Gemfile:
source 'http://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Windows only
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~>6.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-datatables'

gem "omniauth", "~> 1.9.1"
gem 'devise'

gem 'pg'
gem 'geokit'
gem "chartkick", '~>2.3.5'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'openlayers-rails'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

gem 'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 10.2.0.0'
# Use Puma as the app server

gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'execjs','~> 2.7.0'

gem "roo", "~> 2.7.0"
gem 'activerecord-import'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'listen'

end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'whenever', require: false


I Did try to raise the version of bootstrap, and the version of rails to 7. however as it didn't work I reversed it.
I Did search StackOverflow but only found similar "(no implicit conversion of String into Integer)" errors.
Stacktrace below:
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:176:in `initialize'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:176:in `open'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:176:in `exec_runtime'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:14:in `initialize'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:57:in `new'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:57:in `compile'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:44:in `eval'
autoprefixer-rails (10.2.0.0) lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:134:in `runtime'
autoprefixer-rails (10.2.0.0) lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:35:in `process'
autoprefixer-rails (10.2.0.0) lib/autoprefixer-rails/sprockets.rb:22:in `run'
autoprefixer-rails (10.2.0.0) lib/autoprefixer-rails/sprockets.rb:16:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:201:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.7.5) lib/sprockets/base.rb:92:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:357:in `find_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:347:in `find_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:169:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.5.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:169:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:38


This isn't directly related to your issue but do yourself a huge favor and install WSL2 and some flavor of Linux such as Ubuntu. It's not that hard compared to dealing with all the issues of running Rails and whatever gems your app requires on Windows. The lack of dev/prod parity when you're developing on a completely different OS will bite you in the ass too sooner or later. https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

The actual error here occurs when the stylesheet is compiled by sprockets. The execjs gem provides a JS runtime embedded in Ruby. This approach is extremely outdated as its trivial today to just install an actual JS runtime such as Node.js via your package manager of choice. execjs is especially problematic on Windows.
